# Can't decode Python error in Russian/Ukrainian

Tags: python, utf-8

I receive an error from API I'm using

```
 except Exception as e:
     return {
        "error":  str(e),
        "senderInfo": None,
        "signInfo": None
      }
```

And I can't see or decode the error message from it which is in Ukrainian

```
{'ErrorCode': 51, 'ErrorDesc': b'\\xd0\\xa1\\xd0\\xb5\\xd1\\x80\\xd1\\x82\\xd0\\xb8\\xd1\\x84\\xd1\\x96\\xd0\\xba\\xd0\\xb0\\xd1\\x82 \\xd0\\xbd\\xd0\\xb5 \\xd0\\xb7\\xd0\\xbd\\xd0\\xb0\\xd0\\xb9\\xd0\\xb4\\xd0\\xb5\\xd0\\xbd\\xd0\\xbe'}
```

I know how to decode normal strings but since I receive this as an error I'm not sure how to decode it to normal utf-8 characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace double backslashes with a single backslash and use `decode('utf-8')`

```py
a=b'\xd0\xa1\xd0\xb5\xd1\x80\xd1\x82\xd0\xb8\xd1\x84\xd1\x96\xd0\xba\xd0\xb0\xd1\x82 \xd0\xbd\xd0\xb5 \xd0\xb7\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb9\xd0\xb4\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbd\xd0\xbe'
a.decode('utf-8')

> 'Сертифікат не знайдено'
```